# How can I suppress or eliminate connectivity warnings in Google Earth?

Tags: c#, google-earth

I'm using earthlib in C# to use Google Earth in one of my forms. However, the computer on which my program is going to run will not be connected to the Internet. I copied the cache files and modified the registry so that Google Earth can run offline.

But when my program runs, Google Earth goes into diagnostics mode and asks me whether I want to check online for solutions. After I tell it not to do so it tries to check something at kh.google.com, and when it can't do that another message shows up and says that Google Earth couldn't connect to the page.

Is there a way to prevent Google Earth from doing these things or at least to suppress these messages?